# Can polarized light be unpolarized again?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, waves

I was just wondering if there could be a process that could unpolarize polarazied light. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Un-polarized light is just a superposition of many polarizations. Even if you are in vacuum you can use some beam splitters in cascade to obtain many rays, change (rotate) the polarization of each one in a different way, and then recombine the beam.

Comment: That raises an interesting question.  How many beams do you need?  Is two enough?  If I combine two beams with orthogonal polarization and equal intensity can I distinguish it from a randomly polarized beam?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold And, as a related and perhaps more practical question, could I use this property to transmit multiple signals at once through a fiber optic cable?

Comment: @Ajedi32, I think most fibers scramble the polarization state of the light... there is special fiber.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization-maintaining_optical_fiber

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I suspect that if you use an ideal beam and split it in only two, the recombined one will be diagonal polarized or circular (elliptical) polarized  according to the phase difference of the two paths. This will probably be eased if the incoming light has some incoherency/chromatics.

Answer (score 7):

Use the light to excite a gas. The re-emission would be un-polarized.

That is given you have enough energy in the wave to do so. That's one way I could think of off my head.

**EDIT:** As per DarioP's suggestion, a solid fluorescent material would be nicer, as it is certainly more opaque than a gas.I am not aware of emission characteristics of a fluoroscent material, but in general, it should emit unpolarized light

Comment: Isn't it against the intuition? Electric field vectors from one of the planes have been absorbed by the polarizer , how can they get regenerated after hitting a gas molecule?

Comment: @Swami Use another polarizer at a different angle, in combination with your original polarizer. The new direction has a component in the planes where the original vector was absorbed by the first polarizer.
Nothing too surprising.

Comment: Uhmm, this is not obvious to me. You can use a gas to polarize unpolarized light (observing at 90° - try with the Sun and the sky!) but I'm not sure if the other way   somehow happens.

Comment: @DarioP I am not sure if it does, but here is my chain of logic. Excited gas produces unpolarized light(general direction). Use the polarized light to excite a gas. It hould emit unpolarized light.

But, on a slightly unrelated tone on your doubt, but relevant to my previous comment, for the equations and all, with a nice connection to particle spin and quantum theory see Baym 1969, the first chapter.

Comment: I think that it is better to employ some fluorescent solid material that can interact much more with light. A gas (in common conditions) will let most of the light through without any interaction (indeed normally air does not glow).

Comment: @DarioP Yeah, that'd be nice. As I mentioned in the answer, excited gas was the first thing that came to my mind.
Fluoroscent solid material makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what is unpolarized light?

As Feynman said,
''Light is unpolarized if you cannot tell whether it is polarized or not.''

Light from ordinary sources is unpolarized because our detectors can only detect the mixture of waves polarized in different directions. (not individual waves).

Waves emitted by any one molecule may be linearly polarized. Still, an ordinary light source contains a large number of molecules with random orientations, so the emitted light is a random mixture of waves linearly polarized in all possible transverse directions. So light from an ordinary light source is unpolarized.

Now to answer your question just mix light polarized in different directions so that our detectors cannot detect the individual light and you will have unpolarized light.